# Unable to run python script on boot

Tags: python, ssh, cron

I wrote a script for object detection and if I establish ssh connection to Raspberry Pi and run it from console, everything works fine. As I would like to start the script automatically on boot, I added the entry to the cron table:

@reboot cd /home/pi/workspace/counting-objects && python3 script.py

In the script, I have added following lines before and after import to check whether the import is the issue as I noticed the script was not running:

```
logger.info("[INFO] Importing libraries for openvino...")
from openvino.inference_engine import IENetwork, IEPlugin
logger.info("[INFO] libraries imported successfully")
```

In the log file, I saw the first line and the second line was missing, which means an error occurred while trying to import openvino library.

Does anyone know if there is a way to "emulate ssh connection environment" or anyhow solve this issue? The problem is that the issue cannot be reproduced if the script is ran from console.

Comment: the issue may be the difference between running it as user `pi` vs running it as `root` - there's many ways to run things on boot (cron isn't my choice, but whatever) - and each method has its own way of running as a chosen user - that's what I'd be looking for  edit: removed link, because it was written by a numpty

Comment: You know you can probably see what the error is in the cron log?

Answer (score 0):

Create a **systemd** unit file with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl --force --full edit myscript.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, save them and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Description=My script
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
User=pi
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/workspace/counting-objects
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/workspace/counting-objects/script.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If the script is running all the time in the background like a service and not only one short time at startup then just omit the two lines `Type=oneshot` and `RemainAfterExit=yes`.

Enable the service with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable myscript.service
```

Reboot and check the status with:

```
rpi ~$ systemctl status myscript.service
```